# Editing a second Excel file and wait until closed to continue

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first post, so please be kind.

I have an Excel 2010 VBA macro inside File1.xlsm, which needs to open a second Excel file, File2.xlsx, wait for the second file to be manually edited by the user and closed before it continues.  I have no problem opening the second Excel file, but have not been able to figure out how to get the macro to wait until the second file is closed to continue.

Having done some research on this, I tried to adapt suggestions from other similar posts that used Sleep/IsFileOpen in a loop or brought up a message box or user form to temporarily halt processing of the macro.  In all of those cases, the second file was opened, but focus was always maintained on the first file that contains the macro.  The end result is that I had to close the user form or message box without being able to edit the second file.  In the case of the Sleep loop, the Sleep caused all of Excel to Sleep and the application went into an infinite loop checking to see if the file was still open followed by sleeping for 1 second.

Sorry in advance, but the complete listing exists in a closed space and is too complex to re-create here for posting.

I thought this would be simple to start a macro running, have it open a second Excel file, have the user edit/save/close the file and then continue the macro using the updated file.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `On Timer` rather than sleeping?  So fire a macro every 10 seconds (or whatever) and, in that macro, either (if the file is still open) just fire itself off in another 10 seconds or (if the file is closed) do whatever processing you want to do.

Comment: Is there a specific update the user is doing? Or will it be different everytime? If its always similar, then you can ask for the update prior to opening the new document, load the document and put it in with code then save and close with code.

Comment: YowE3K - No, I haven't tried that.  Sounds like a good solution.  Editing can be done in a separate instantiation of Excel.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Geoff - The document represents a library of information that can be added to, deleted from or edited.  Being a library, there is no way to know in advance what information the user wants to change.  The current method is doing just as you suggested where updates are added prior to running the code.  I'm looking to a more automated method.